# A field or property with the name [database column] was not found on the selected data source

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I get this weird error when programming in Visual Studio 2010. I have a column in SQL Server named "tag_id". It is the primary key for my table. If I attempt to use "tag_id" in any reference in Visual Studio, rather it be like this

```
<asp:BoundField  DataField="tag_id" HeaderText="Current Tags"/>
```

or this

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO [tag_names] ([tag_id], [name], [created_by], [created_date]) VALUES ('{0}','{1}', '{2}', GETDATE())";
```

ANYWHERE I use it. I get various different errors depending on the usage, but the gist is that it's telling me that column tag_id doesn't exist. But it does! The only way to get this code to work is for me to copy "tag_id" from SQL Server, the literal word "tag_id" and paste it into Visual Studio. Although the spelling is exactly the same, it won't work unless I copy and paste it from SQL Server. Additionally, if I copy and paste a query from Visual Studio and put it in SQL Server, it says that "tag_id" is not found. It's as if the text in Visual Studio just doesn't work for this column. All other columns I have no problems with if I just enter the name.

Has anyone seen this before?

UPDATE:

After reading Gordon and Grantly's suggestions I tried to inspect the underscore. For that one column, "tag_id" when I copy and paste it from Visual Studio to notepad++ it shows up as "tag_id". When I copy and paste "tag_id" from SQL Server it comes up as "tagUS_id". Even when I paste it in here it just says "tag_id" I had to manually add the "US". But in notepad++ it says "tag" then no spaces and the letters "US" highlighted in black, then "id".

This only happens with this column. Other columns with underscores work fine. Other primary keys work fine, other foreign keys work fine. hmmmmm?

Comment: If I had to guess, the underscores are probably different.  There are examples of short and long underscores.  I must admit, though, that I've only seen this problem with hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

I would concur with Gordon Linoff, that the actual ASCII / Unicode code for the underscore is different for some reason.  Try capturing the VS 2010 lines in a text file (which it probably is already), and also saving your SQL query to file.  Then compare the ASCII / Unicode values for all the characters in tag_id (especially the underscore) and you *should* find a difference.  Its likely to have the Hex value of 5F if its normal ASCII, but you may indeed be inadvertently using Unicode in Visual Studio.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwy0e8f2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

There is an option in Visual Studio under Text Editor General - Auto detect UTF-8 encoding without signature which may or may not cause these differences.

See the See Also section here for alternative Unicode chars for the underscore:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5f/index.htm.

(I would have simply commented, but not enough reputation)

NB: Notepad++ is free and easy to use, use TextFX Convert feature to show the text converted to various forms (HEX 32 would be useful).  I prefer VEdit

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution, but after investigating many options, I was unable to find the root cause to the issue. I just deleted the table in Microsoft SQL Server and recreated it. After that everything worked as expected.